# String format in hyperlink

Tags: c#, string, hyperlink, format

Trying desperately to create a simple link. I wish it could be made directly on the aspx page but do not manage to have the link displayed properly despite my attempts below. I know I can do it easily through the underlying .cs page but I would like to avoid if possible. Is there any way to do this?

```
   <a id="A2" runat="server"
      href='<%# String.Format("~/Users/DisplayUserDetails.aspx?selectedUserID={0}", 
      selectedExtMobProfileDetailled.loginUserId.Value )%>'>
  <%= selectedExtMobProfileDetailled.loginUserId.Value %> T1</a>

<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink6" runat="server"
    NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/Users/DisplayUserDetails.aspx?selectedUserID={0}",
    Eval("selectedExtMobProfileDetailled.loginUserId.Value"))%>'>
    <%= selectedExtMobProfileDetailled.loginUserId.Value %> T2</asp:HyperLink>

<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" Enabled="true"
    NavigateUrl='<%= String.Format("~/Users/DisplayUserDetails.aspx?selectedUserID={0}",
     Eval("selectedExtMobProfileDetailled.loginUserId.Value "))%>'>
  <%= selectedExtMobProfileDetailled.loginUserId.Value%>T3</asp:HyperLink>

</td>


<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" Enabled="true"
       NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/Users/DisplayUserDetails.aspx?selectedUserID={0}",
       selectedExtMobProfileDetailled.loginUserId.Value)%>'><%= selectedExtMobProfileDetailled.loginUserId.Value%>T4</asp:HyperLink>


<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" Enabled="true" 
               NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/Users/DisplayUserDetails.aspx?selectedUserID={0}",
"test")%>'> <%= selectedExtMobProfileDetailled.loginUserId.Value%> T5</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: Can I ask why dont you want to do it in code behind, this looks messy already

Comment: Because this is a simple link (I posted the multiple attempts) and I have several of them in the aspx page. This is to avoid having those purely formatting points polluting the cs file. But if I need to give up I will.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this

```
<%# String.Format(...)%>
```

that's for binding,

Instead use `=` operator

```
<%= String.Format(..)%>
```

Comment: Yes, as you can see above I believe that I tried nearly all combinations without success...